# Threads don't behave properly, c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have been trying to use multithreading lately to speed up my codes, but it hasn't been going great.

I have this simple logic in the code I'm currently developing:

```
Start Main Code
{
    //code
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => {list1 = Method1();});
    thread1.Start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => {list2 = Method2();});
    thread2.Start();
    //more code
    thread1.Join();
    ListA = list1;
    thread2.Join();
    ListB = list2;
    return whatever;
}
```

I would expect that thread1 and thread2 run alongside the main code and then meet at the Join()'s, but for some reason my code jumps all over and gets to the return statement seemingly randomly, without even going trough the entire main code.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Edit:

I´m sorry for not being clear in my question.
What I mean is this:

Code starts at line 1, as expected, then runs normally until it meets the Thread.Start()'s I declared. Then it countinues to run normally for a few more lines, until suddenly it jumps straigth to the "return whatever" line at the end of the main code block.

I know that when debugging this kind of code it jumps all over the methods I create, that is not the problem I face. The problem, as I mentioned, is the out of the blue jump to the end of the code.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.1.

Comment: Can you define what `Method1` and `Method2` do? Sometimes if the task is very short, you won't see overlap. Threads share the same processor time and this time is split throughout the running threads. a thread will run for say, 100 ticks (arbitrary), and when it's done with these 100 ticks, another thread will work for another 100 ticks. This is probably why you don't see any overlap.

Comment: Both methods retrieved some data from a DataBase and add it to a custom Class I created. Method2 is significantly shorther than Method1 though.

The main problem I face is that the threads seem to break the code. The Main code block does not go trough all the lines it should, it jumps straight to the return statement for some reason.

Comment: why not use the Async framework way of doing things?
using Task<T> should be the way to go.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'jumps all over' and gets to the 'return statement'? Which return statement? `return whatever`? Or within `Method1`/`Method2`?

Comment: If the main thread jumps strangely around you might need to clean the solution to make sure that the executed code is in sync with the source files.

Comment: Does "code jumps all over" mean that the debugger keeps switching between threads when you're stepping through your code? Because that's quite normal.

Comment: I added some clarifications to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven‘t specified which version of the .NET framework, I am going to assume you can use the async framework.
This code will run both tasks in parallel if need be and should only take as long as the longest task you have. Instead of `Task.Delay()` you would have your own code which actually goes to the db and retrieve the data.

(Running version of the code below https://dotnetfiddle.net/CCCfKw)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doWork = new SomeWorkClass();

        var list1Task = doWork.GetList1Async();
        var list2Task = doWork.GetList2Async();

        var list1 = list1Task.Result;
        var list2 = list2Task.Result;

        var newList = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();

        foreach(var str in newList) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}

public class SomeWorkClass
{
    private List<string> _list1 = new List<string>() { "Some text 1", "Some other text 2" };
    private List<string> _list2 = new List<string>() { "Yet more text 3" };

    public async Task<List<string>> GetList1Async()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return _list1;
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetList2Async()
    {
        await Task.Delay(700);
        return _list2;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is an UI application, your code can deadlock. [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Thx, I'll try it as soon as I can.